# How can I delete odd photos on my iPad without deleting them on daughters phone which is linked by applie Id using iOS 12

Tags: iphone

Hi I’m not great on these devices and have searched for the answer but my screens don’t appear the same so apologies if already answered . 
I have an iPad and iPhone and my daughter also has iPhone and we both  use my Apple ID ( she’s only 9); how do we delete odd photos and notes from one device without them deleting off the others . Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be reluctant to set up an account for your daughter, for various legitimate reasons, but Apple's recommendation is to do just that, and to link the two accounts via "family sharing"

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201084

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I tried to set up a new Id but it said she was too young ?